How to access resources in private subnets of one vpc to another peered vpc?
I have two VPCs A and B. VPC A has 3 public and 3 private subnets. My eks cluster is deployed in 3 public subnets of VPC A (due to lack of IP addresses in public subnets there is a secondary CIDR as a private IP range.) VPC B also has 3 public and 3 private subnets. My Amazon aurora databases and Opersearch service instances are in private subnets of VPC B(also some S3 buckets in VPC B). How can the eks pods from VPC A communicate to aurora, s3 and Opensearch service in VPC B?
There is a peering connection between VPC A and B.
How can I use NAT gateway or VPC Endpoints to access services in private subnets of VPC B from VPC A?
Due to network size limits in one VPC, we have to create two VPCs with peering and divide the services.

Have you tried step-by-step guide? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/peering/create-vpc-peering-connection.html Note, you should complete "Create" and "Accept" steps

@AlexanderPavlov yes peering connection and route tables are correct

NAT Gateway is used to access the Internet, it is not required for connectivity between VPCs. VPC Endpoints are used to obtain connectivity to AWS services, it is not required for connectivity between VPCs. What is the configuration of the Route Tables in the two subnets that contain the services you wish to connect?

there is a route via vpc peering connection in both the vpc route tables

How about security groups? Did you update security group to accept connection from the other VPC CIDR/Subnets?

Yes...security groups are in place but do we need to use nat gateway or any VPC endpoints ? or its simply possible with security groups ?
